# adding buttons at custom places in windowsform c# panel

Tags: c#, button, layout

I have been trying it for hours but can not get it to work, i have to implement a binary search tree using panels and buttons in c# so far what i did was take input from text area and make a button with a text value on it, now i have to show the buttons in a hierarchy fashion to make a tree. I am confused about what tools i can use to complete my task, and i just started C# yesterday i don't have much knowledge about it. More guidance on this topic will be greatly helpful to me Thanks here is the code so far!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        string value;
        int z=30;
        int y=100;
        List<Panel> ls = new List<Panel>();
        Button main = new Button();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void retrieveInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            value = this.inputText.Text;
            long number1= 0;
            bool canConvert = long.TryParse(value, out number1);
            if (canConvert == true)
            {
                Button button1 = new Button();
               Panel pan = new Panel();
                ls.Add(pan);
                pan.Location = new Point(10, z * 100);
                pan.Size = new Size(200, 90);  // just an example
                this.Controls.Add(pan);
                button1.Click +=(Onb2Click);
                button1.Text = value;
                button1.Width = 100;//this.Width - 10;
                button1.Height = 30;
                pan.Controls.Add(button1);
                pan.Location = new Point(10, z * 100);
                z = z + 30;
                pan.Size = new Size(200, 90);  // just an example
                this.Controls.Add(pan);
                panel1.Controls.Add(pan);

            }
            else
            {
               // Console.WriteLine("numString is not a valid long");

            }   
        }

        private void inputText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            value = this.inputText.Text;
           // retrieveInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e);

        }

        void Onb2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void flowLayoutPanel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            z++;
            y++;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Is this homewoek or why don't you use the ready TreeView there is? A FLP will fill itself, so you will have to put in dummies of margins before each 'node'. How do you/ the user create the hierarchy? Do you have a sketch of the desired outcome?

Comment: Yes it is a homework and i solved my problem i inserted buttons using datagrid but so far i am able to implement just one level bst tree its not adding further buttons. guide me through if i can use some reliable method to do this assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use `TreeView` control instead.
Much easyer to handle Parent-Child display flow

Comment: I tried with so far with the panel and flowlayout, flowlayout automatically positions the buttons in a flow manner and by using panel it adds the button only once, i dont either to use loops or continue pool the input field to check for the input, i am so confused right now :(